# Version mismatch between ChromeDriver & Chrome when running Protractor tests, but no update available

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, webdriver, webdriver-manager

I am trying to run Protractor tests on my Angular app, but am facing an issue with my version of ChromDriver not matching my version of Chrome.

I'm able to run `webdriver-manager start` fine with no issues, but when I try to run my tests I get this error message:

> SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'

I checked my version of Chrome & that is version 84. But when I try to update Chrome it says that my version is up to date.

So I have 2 questions:

(1) How come this latest version (85) of Chrome isn't available to me?

(2) Is there a way I can downgrade my webdriver so that it picks up version 84 of Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered this question here as well:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5460
The easiest possible fix is to use:

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=84.0.4147.30
webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome=84.0.4147.30
```

to update and start the webdriver server. This forces the version to stay to 84. What I think happened v85 of the chromedriver was added and labelled as latest (you can see this [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/)) which forced webdriver-manager to start downloading version 85 (it by default downloads the latest version).

Comment: This is a fantastic solution, saved me a lot of heart ache, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't generally start the webdriver-manager server with `webdriver-manager start`. Here is another solution you can try which I also posted in a discussion on the [webdriver-manager issue 376](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/376#issuecomment-663560439)

Here is the copied work-around (this is just a stop-gap since obviously we don't want to hard-code the version):

1. We have webdriver-manager installed as project dependency (`npm install --save-dev webdriver-manager`)
2. we call `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 84.0.4147.30` prior to running our tests. This will install the 84 chromedriver version in ./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/. (We just made this as a npm script in our package.json)
3. We then update the protractor.conf file to have this line in the root of exports.config: `chromeDriver:"./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_84.0.4147.30.exe"`**

Protractor still installs chromedriverr 85, but it will use the 84 version.

** In our case, we run our protractor tests in docker, but develop mostly on windows. So I updated the protractor.conf to have this line so that it works in either:
`chromeDriver: process.platform === "win32" ? "./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_84.0.4147.30.exe" : "./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_84.0.4147.30"`